# Olympiad Mathematical of Kosovo 2011 (Problem grade 9)

Tags: contest-math

A little boy wrote the numbers $1,2,3,...,2011$  on a blackboard. He picks any two numbers $x,y$ , erases them with a sponge and writes the number $ |x-y |$. This process continues until only one number is left. Prove that the number left is even

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Show that, at every step of the process, the sum of the numbers on the blackboard is even.

Comment: Ah, you got ahead of me.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Usually, one of the first things to try when dealing with questions of "even or odd" is to compute everything modulo 2. If that doesn't work, modulo 4 and modulo 8 are often the next thing to try.